# Terminating a thread in Delphi 10 with Android

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi

I'm creating a thread with the basic settings indicated below. Apparently everything is working fine, but when I run `MyThread.Terminate` I noticed that `Destroy` does not run. `Destroy` is only executed when closing the main application.

**What is the correct way to end a thread?**

BASIC THREAD

```
// MyThread "TPoolingThread"
constructor TPoolingThread.Create;
begin
   inherited Create(True);

   // Initializing something
end;

destructor TPoolingThread.Destroy;
begin
   inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TPoolingThread.Execute;
begin
   try
      while (not Terminated) do begin
         sleep(100);
         // do something
      end;
   finally
      if not Terminated then
         Terminate;
   end;
end;
```

EXECUTING THREAD

```
// Main Application 

   //////////////////////////////////////////
   // Create and Start
   MyThread := TPoolingThread.Create;

   if Assigned(MyThread.FatalException) then
      raise MyThread.FatalException;

   MyThread.Start;

   //////////////////////////////////////////
   // Stop
   MyThread.Terminate;
```

Comment: Delphi uses ARC for object lifetime management on Android. The destructor is not called until all references to the thread object have been cleared. Are you clearing your `MyThread` pointer after calling `Terminate`? Also `FatalException` is only set if an uncaught exception escapes from `Execute`, so it will *never* be set in the code you showed. You can check for it in the `OnTerminate` event instead. If `Create` fails, it will raise an exception that is not stored in `FatalException`

Comment: No, I'm not clearing my MyThread pointer after calling Terminate. My basic code is only that. Should I do MyThread = nil? About `FatalException`, ok. I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: Your edit made a mess of things. You don't Terminate or thread from its Execute method.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I followed an example from Embarcadero, where they using `try except` I used `try finally`. Is `finally` wrong? I just want to make the thread ends gracefully and I'm not understanding the most correct way just by using the debug. The Embarcadero example is: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Handling_Exceptions_in_the_Thread_Function . Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, that example is about handling exceptions not about calling `Terminate` from within `Execute` method. Next, even though calling `Terminate` itself doesn't do any harm, it shows complete lack of understanding of threads. Also there is huge difference between `except` and `finally`. I suggest you familiarize yourself with the basic Delphi programming concepts before you jump doing any multithreading. Right now you are just randomly putting pieces of code together hoping it will magically work. You have to understand what each and every piece does before you can combine them together.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention. It may seem that I am wanting magic solutions, but that is not my goal. Everything I'd like to know from the beginning is the right way to end a thread, but I see that the simple fact that I try and try again to get an answer, raises wrong impression that I don't want to seek information myself. Sorry if it sounded like that, because it is not my intention. I'm just looking for answers. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I am not saying that you are not willing to look for answers yourself, I am saying that you have too much to learn. And that you have to start learning one step at the time.

Comment: How to terminate thread - use Terminate method (outside of the thread Execute method). Why is Destroy not called upon termination - because it has nothing to do with terminating the thread. And the rest turned into debugging session I cannot help you with because problem is in your other code I cannot see. I suggest you edit this question again - make complete and minimal example of the problems you face and maybe someone will answer.

Comment: It's no longer necessary to edit the code, because the code posted was just thinking about minimal as possible to ask a question. Your answer about `Terminate` has been enough. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to preface my answer by defining *'ending a thread'*. I'm going to assume that by *'ending a thread'* you mean to stop your loop in the `TPoolingThread.Execute` procedure.

**Terminating the thread**

The method you use to terminate your thread is perfectly acceptable. Now as to why it is, allow me to show you [this snippet](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=try):

> Version 1
>
> In a Try-Finally construct, the Finally statement is guaranteed to be executed absolutely regardless of what happens in the try clause. However, the Finally clause does not actually handle any exceptions - the program will terminate if no Except clause is found (see notes below).

Therefore if your code within your loop throws an exception, you tell your `TPoolingThread` object that it has been terminated.

**Why destroy isn't getting called**

As [Remy Lebeau and Dalija Prasnikar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820633/5150422) suggest. [Terminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Terminate) is not supposed to call destroy:

> System.Classes.TThread.Terminate:
>
> Signals the thread to terminate by setting the Terminated property to true.
>   Terminate sets the thread's Terminated property to true, signaling that the thread should be terminated as soon as possible.
>
> For Terminate to work, the thread's Execute method and any methods that Execute calls should check Terminated periodically and exit when it's true.

I will leave you [this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers) if you want to find out more about ARC in Delphi for Android development.

Comment: Sorry, but `try...finally` inside `Execute` method where finally block consists only of checking `Terminated` and calling `Terminate` is completely useless.   If exception is raised, thread will be terminated - it will exit `Execute` method anyway. Also unhandled exception inside the thread will crash the application.